# Analytic variety can be defined by finitely many equations

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C^n$. $V:=\{z\in\mathbb C^n\mid f_i(z)=0,\forall i\}$. I know that locally we could write down the equation with finitely many equations because the local ring $\mathscr{O}_0$ of the analytic sheaf is Noetherian.

But it this also true globally? First, we know that the ring of all holomorphic functions on $\mathbb C^n$ is not Noetherian.

I attempted like this assume $I_0(V):=\{f\in \mathscr{O}_0\mid f|_V=0\}$ is an ideal of  $\mathscr{O}_0$, so it is finitely generated say by $(g_1,...,g_m)$. Then when we localize any $f_i$ to $\mathscr{O}_0$, we can write $f_{i,x}=r_1g_1+...+r_mg_m$. This means they coninside on  an open neighborhood. Then apply identity theorem. But later when I reviewed it, it was not that correct, because the functions $g_1,r_1,...,r_m,g_m$ might actually not be globally defined. So maybe this claim is wrong? is there any counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true, even if you replace ${\mathbb C}^n$ by an $n$-dimensional complex manifold $M$. The precise statement is that if $V\subset M$ is the zero-set of a family of holomorphic functions $f_j, j\in J$, on $M$ then there are  holomorphic functions $g_1,...g_n$ on $M$ such that
$$
V=\{z\in M: g_i(z)=0, i=1,...,n\}. 
$$

See Proposition 5.7 in

E.M. Chirka, "Complex analytic sets." Translated from the Russian by R. A. M. Hoksbergen, Mathematics and Its Applications: Soviet Series, 46. Dordrecht etc.: Kluwer Academic Publishers. xix, 372 p. Dfl. 195.00; (1989).

Comment: Ah thank you. But it seems not that trivial? I thought it was as "trivial" as the algebraic cases.

Comment: @CO2: It is not very hard, but is not a trivial result. Many things work differently in the complex-analytic category, comparing to the algebro-geometric one.

Comment: Thank you. At the beginning, I found it is very hard because the ring of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ is not Noetherian. Afterwards, I found these Weierstrasse preparation theorems. I thought it became easy. But, eventually, there is still a (smal)l issue. So assume we proved the fact that the local ring at $0$ is Noetherian. Then for any family of holomorphic functions $f_i$, we could reduce them to a finite number of functions, say $f_1,f_2,...,f_N$. But this is done locally on the stalk. Say $f_i$ is any other function in the original family. We could write $f_i=g_1f_1+...+g_Nf_N$.

Comment: But this is done on a small open neighborhood $V_i$. We need to find a neighborhood $V$ so that all $f_i$ from the family is written in this way. But the problem is $V_i$ depends on $_fi$ what if the set gets smaller and smaller?

Comment: @CO2 You can also use Cartan's Theorem A.